# c++ projecteuler #4 code mistake

Tags: c++, palindrome, digit

I'm trying to solve the problem given in [Project Euler #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4):

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

There aren't any compilation errors in my solution...but program doesn't provide the correct output.  I think I have made some mistake in defining boolean function.

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int z) {      
    // store z in t to compare it later with its reversed number
    int t = z;
    int rev = 0;
    
    // This while loop reverses the number
    while (z > 0) {
        int dig = z % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + dig;
        z = z / 10;
    }
    
    if (t == rev) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void palindrome(int k) {
    int b = 0;
    int a = pow(10, k);
    
    // calculate product of two numbers
    // replace it if it's palindrome and greater than previously stored value b
    
    // for loop to calculate product of all 3 (in general k) digit numbers
    for (int i = pow(10,k-1); i = pow (10,k) - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j = pow (10,k) - 2; j++) {
            int c = i * j;                             

        if (isPalindrome(c) && c > b) {
            b = c;
            }
        }
    } 
    
    cout << "Largest Palindrome = " << b << endl;
}

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the digit length" <<"\t"; 
    cin >> n;

    palindrome(n);

    return 0;
}
```

For an example of it not working, I tried inputting n=3 and it just hangs, with no output.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "the program does not work?"

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please keep the comments on topic. Arguing about whether or not the comments are rude is the very definition of off-topic.

Comment: I'm using devcpp. When I click compile and run , input console opens.
After I  put 3 as input, nothing happens

Comment: @user3485318 It's unclear what you're asking, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem is in the line,

```
for (int i = pow(10,k-1); i = pow (10,k) - 2; i++) {
```

Consider how your loop is going to terminate.